# In Presto how can I check if an element in an array is present in a list I acquire via a subquery

Tags: sql, arrays, presto

This is a Presto SQL question.

I have a table `Test` with an array field called `mitigations`.

How can I check if there is any element in this array that is present in a subquery which is

`(select distinct(ID) from other_table)`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ARRAYS_OVERLAP` and `ARRAY_AGG` functions as

```
select * from Test where 
   ARRAYS_OVERLAP(mitigations, (select ARRAY_AGG(ID) from other_table))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ANY` function to check if there is an element inside an array

Consider the following example

```
CREATE TABLE sal_emp (
    name            text,
    pay_by_quarter  integer[]
);

INSERT INTO sal_emp
    VALUES 
    ('Bill','{40000, 10000, 30000, 10000}'),
    ('Jack','{10000, 50000, 20000, 10000}');
```

*We want to check if there are 10,000 numbers in the array*

```
SELECT * FROM sal_emp
where 10000 = ANY (pay_by_quarter);
```

*The same query above in another way*

```
SELECT name FROM sal_emp
WHERE pay_by_quarter IN
(SELECT pay_by_quarter FROM sal_emp WHERE 10000 = ANY (pay_by_quarter));
```

[Declaration of Array Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html)

[Array Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html)

Comment: I am having troubles implementing this idea into my situation.  My list is coming from another table.  If I could convert that list to an array I could do an "arrays_overlap" function.